# How statement completion works in RubyMine 7

Tags: ruby, rubymine-7

I am using `RubyMine7.1.4` to write my test cases in `Ruby`. Its an awesome `Ruby IDE`, but it seems like I am not using totally.

For example: If we type **syso** in `eclipse` and press enter it will give `System.out.println();`

How to do that in `RubyMine7.1.4`?
typing **lpl** gives `$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic type nature of Ruby is such that you will never have quite the same level of autocomplete as you were seeing with Java.  Instead the autocompletion is more context based.

That said; you can go to the main menu and set Code | Complete Code | SmartType.  This may give you code completion that is more to your liking; but your mileage may vary.